TypeScript Bug : Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>
This is my App.tsx file. So I was following a video with JavaScript, but while writing that in TypeScript VS Code is showing these bugs:
Source Code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './output.css'; // Adjust path if necessary
import {auth, provider} from './config' ;
import { signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import Home from './Home';

function SignIn(){

  const [value,setValue] = useState('')
  const handleClick = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((data) => {
      setValue(data.user.email)
      localStorage.setItem("email", data.user.email)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(localStorage.getItem('email'))
  })

return (
  <div>
  {value?<Home/>:
    <button onClick={handleClick} className='px-2 bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-900 pt-2 pb-2 pl-3 pr-3 rounded-md'>Sign in with Google</button>
  }
  </div>
);
}
export default SignIn;


In line 12: data.user.email Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)
(property) UserCredential.user: User
In line 12: data.user.email Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
In line 18: localStorage.getItem('email') Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)
I expected writing js in ts would not make problem but in ts as i need to give certain types to variables may be that's why these errors are occuring...
How to fix this?

Your file has the extension .tsx, which means it's a TypeScript file. VS Code and your build process will therefore apply type checking to the content, regardless whether you use types yourself.
Rename the file to App.jsx and the type errors should be gone.

I see, but what if I want to write the same thing in .tsx what changes need to do?

tl;dr: you have to learn TypeScript :)
The errors you listed mean that some values you are using could be null, so you either have to make sure they do contain a value before using them (e.g. if (data.user.email) { setValue(data.user.email) }), or provide a fallback value (setValue(data.user.email ?? '')).

This should do the work:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './output.css'; // Adjust path if necessary
import {auth, provider} from './config' ;
import { signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import Home from './Home';

function SignIn(){

  const [value,setValue] = useState('')
  const handleClick = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((data) => {
      if(data.user.email){ // this will check if email is string
         // this will only run if email is a string
         setValue(data.user.email)
         localStorage.setItem("email", data.user.email)
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedEmail = localStorage.getItem('email');
    if(storedEmail) { // this will check if an email was stored in localstorage
       setValue(storedEmail); // storedEmail: string
    }
  })

return (
  <div>
  {value?<Home/>:
    <button onClick={handleClick} className='px-2 bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-900 pt-2 pb-2 pl-3 pr-3 rounded-md'>Sign in with Google</button>
  }
  </div>
);
}
export default SignIn;

